# Splitting a string on the double pipe(||) using String.split()

Tags: java, split

I'm trying to split the string with double pipe(||) being the delimiter.String looks something like this:

```
String str ="user@email1.com||user@email2.com||user@email3.com";
```

i'm able to split it using the StringTokeniser.The javadoc says the use of this class is discouraged and instead look at String.split as option.

```
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(str, "||");
```

The above code works fine.But not able to figure out why below string.split function not giving me expected result..

```
String[] strArry = str.split("\\||");
```

Where am i going wrong..?

Comment: What's your expected result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`String.split()` uses regular expressions. You need to escape the string that you want to use as divider.

Pattern has a method to do this for you, namely [`Pattern.quote(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String[] split = str.split(Pattern.quote("||"));
```

Answer (score 16):

You must escape every single `|` like this `str.split("\\|\\|")`

Comment: isn't it "\|\|"? Am I mistaken?

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary you also must escape the `\\` since is also a meta character

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary You also need to escape the `\\`, because it's the Java string escape sequence.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary Because it's RegEx, you need to escape `|` as `\|`.  But because the RegEx is being built from a string, you need to additionally escape \ as \\.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary No, because that would be a Java-escape, but we want a regex-escape

Comment: Oh, didn't know `|` was a regex char. I'll get the hang of that regex soon :p

Comment: @gtgaxiola Oh ok, thanks, I didn't use this yet just with \"! I mean not with regex

Answer (score 4):

try this bellow    :

```
String[] strArry = str.split("\\|\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too...

```
String[] splits = str.split("[\\|]+");
```

Please note that you have to escape the pipe since it has a special meaning in regular expression and the String.split() method expects a regular expression argument.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can follow two different approaches you can follow whichever suites you best:

**Approach 1:**

**By Using String SPLIT functionality**

```
String str = "a||b||c||d";
String[] parts = str.split("\\|\\|");
```

This will return you an array of different values after the split:

```
parts[0] = "a"
parts[1] = "b"
parts[2] = "c"
parts[3] = "d"
```

**Approach 2:**

**By using PATTERN and MATCHER**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String str = "a||b||c||d";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|\\|");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found two consecutive pipes at index " + m.start());
}
```

This will give you the index positions of consecutive pipes:

```
parts[0] = "a"
parts[1] = "b"
parts[2] = "c"
parts[3] = "d"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String yourstring="Hello || World";
String[] storiesdetails = yourstring.split("\\|\\|");
```